# Storybook action not logging

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm developing a component for a React project in Storybook, but clicking the button doesn't log anything to the action panel. Why doesn't the action log?

The stories...

```
// Button.stories.js
import React from 'react'
import Button from '../components/Button'

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  argTypes: { onClick: { action: 'clicked' } }
}

const Template = args => <Button {...args} />

export const Primary = Template.bind({})
Primary.args = {
  primary: true,
  label: 'Button'
}
```

and the component...

```
// Button.jsx
function Button() {
  const clickHandler = () => {
    alert('!')
  }

  return (
    <button className='button' onClick={clickHandler}>
      Button
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the Story code, are you sure that you use `onClick` Method inside your button component?

Comment: Yep. It works (alert fires) but nothing is logged. I updated the question to include the component code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing  the onClickHandler to Button component, put `{onClickHandler}`  in Button args

And then pass it to the onClick prop in the rendered DOM element.

This way it will make it the on click handler passable by Storybook, and then can be logged by Storybook actions.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `onClick` handler created in the args object to the Button component.

And then call the onClick prop in the Button component `onClickHandler` function.

```js
// Button.stories.js
import React from 'react'
import Button from '../components/Button'

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  argTypes: { onClick: { action: 'button-clicked' } }
}

const Template = args => <Button {...args} />

export const Primary = Template.bind({})
Primary.args = {
  primary: true,
  label: 'Button'
}
```

```
// Button.jsx
function Button(props) {
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    props.onClick('!')
  }

  return (
    <button className='button' onClick={onClickHandler}>
      Button
    </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to handle all actions by hand, then use `argTypesRegex` so they will be inferred automatically.

> ### Automatically matching args
>
> Another option is to use a parameter to match all argTypes that match a certain pattern. The following configuration automatically creates actions for each on argType (which you can either specify manually or can be inferred automatically).

[source](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/actions)

`preview.js/ts` enables you to write regex

Examples:

```js
// preview.ts
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on.*' }
};
```

```js
// preview.js
export default {
  parameters: { actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on.*' } },
};
```